# Parse User Query Only Retrieves Current user

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to run a query that retrieves a specific set of users from the User table and presents them to a given logged in user, using the Parse JS SDK.
At first I was running a query like:

```
(new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extends("_User"))).containedIn("objectId", [/* list of user ids */]).find(/* success & error blocks */);
```

but then I learned the more correct way was:

```
(new Parse.Query(Parse.User)).containedIn("objectId", [/* list of user ids */]).find(/* success & error blocks */);
```

But even with this, I would get back an empty list. I double-checked the db and made sure the ids I was passing were in there, and they were. Just for the hell of it I tried:

```
(new Parse.Query(Parse.User)).find(/* success & error blocks */);
```

And I got back the user object corresponding to the current user. So it seems my User queries are only able to access the current user. I also noticed that when I tried running an equivalent query from the Parse API Console, I got the same results! Is this some sort of global setting, or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not condensing all these calls into one line for the sake of saving lines. It sacrifices readability. Although, it's technically not wrong, and the docs even say the calls return a query so you can chain calls, so to each their own.

I don't see anything wrong with your call, though. How are you accessing the retrieved objects? What is the list of objectIds that you are passing into containedIn? We need a bit more of your code here, I think.

edit - I would say I'm 80% sure, without more information, that this is an ACL / CLP issue. Go to the dashboard, hit the _User class, press Security, and see what the read/write settings are.

Comment: Sorry, that's not actually my exact code, just condensed for the sake of SO brevity.

Comment: There are no retrieved objects, except in the last case. I'm monitoring the network requests. The list is just an array of objectId strings...

Comment: But where do you pull them from? I'd like to see a screen shot of you outputting the array of strings that you are querying for, as well as a screenshot of your database showing that those objectIds do in fact belong to Users for you to query for.

Comment: ...Take my word for it, they do. That is obviously not the issue, or I'd be getting something more back in my last example. I even hardcoded the list in and made sure they were being sent in the network panel.

Comment: Maybe you set some funky class level permissions / ACLs on your users?

Comment: Most likely the case. I inherited the backend so I'm not sure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to use CloudCode due to User Security Settings in Parse. Try shifting this to a cloud code function and include

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()
```

prior to the cloudcode function. This is a security 'feature' of Parse to ensure people can't edit and access other user profiles and information.

See Parse security site here:

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#security-object-level-access-control

and more on use and considerations of implementing useMasterKey() and its persistence.

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#security-implementing-business-logic-in-cloud-code

Comment: Hmmm... That's unfortunate... From my Googling and the SDK, though, it seems like it's possible...Is it just because the user is signed in? Specifically referring to: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-querying

Comment: Wait, from your first link, does this mean this is possible if I query the "_User" object? I just need to read, not write...

Comment: Yeah. I know what you mean. It is not clear in the documentation. I have tried a number of times and run into the same problems. There is a capability of an anonymous user but I doubt that would solve the issue. Cloud Code allows them to secure their user objects since the cloud code can't just be typed into the console.

Comment: it depends on what data you want back. I don't think you get the whole user object that way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a CLP issue to me. Maybe Find permission on your User class is disabled. Go to your User class, tap on security, switch to advance and then check whether the Find permission is ticked off or not.